# "Save Tag Edits" translation not used anymore

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, localization, inline-tag-editor

It seems that "Save Tag Edits" text appeared on self named buttons not used for translations anymore:

> [image: Save Tag Edits]

Transifex returns nothing: [https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english?q=text%3A'Save+Tag+Edits'](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english?q=text%3A%27Save+Tag+Edits%27)

> [image: Transifex]

Traducir says that translation is made: https://ru.traducir.win/strings/4189

> [image: Traducir]

But direct link to transifex returns nothing as well: https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/$?q=key%3A6b259c18b31dc19117983177dd24f847

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It came to life again. Thanks.

> [image]